# Page range field is ignored in wp-paginate plugin

Tags: wordpress

I use http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-paginate/ plugin for paginate the posts.

It ignores "Page Range:" field and shows all pages.

Comment: try to put some code what you have done

Comment: Are you using a plugin because you are not familiar with php? because if you are theres no reason to use a plugin to paginate in wordpress